# up to date chatroom!y

Tags: php, ajax

I am looking to create an ajax powered chatroom for my website.
I have used yshout and it seems very good but crashes when there are too many connections.

What is the best way to go about doing this using the minimum resources possible?

Comment: Crashes how? This is hardly answerable without more detailed data

Comment: Sounds more like your server detects that as a DDoS and thus kicks off the users which appears to be a crash... Just a guess, more informations would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the following::

1. Exceeding the number available threads. Depending on your configuration, you'll have a limit to how many requests can be simultaneously served. Since yshout will be maintaining open connections for longer than normal requests, you're far more likely to exhaust your thread/process limit. See the relevant [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html) for more info (assuming Apache, of course).
2. Exceeding PHP memory limits. For the reasons above, you're likely to need more memory to handle the multiple long running HTTP requests. Try throwing more memory in your server and bumping the PHPs [memory limit](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).